# i am trying to update quantity of product when order is placed but sql is returning garbage value when trying to fetch current value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Ve7.png)
[orderitem table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E5x3.png)

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE var integer;
    SELECT stock INTO var FROM product WHERE pno = new.pid;
    UPDATE product SET s=var,product.stock= var - new.quantity WHERE pno = 
    new.pid;
    END
```

i am trying to update quantity of product when order is placed but sql is returning garbage value when trying to fetch current value

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: Provide complete code (table's DDLs, sample data as INSERT INTO, complete trigger code, INSERT query and desired tables final state).

Comment: mysql phpmyadmin - maybe so but the dbms could be mariadb